# How to split a layer by attributes in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have one layer with multiples Classes (Casa[550], Stock[10], Estrada[20], etc) and I´d like to have those classes as layers.

[image]

E.g: Layer Casa[550], Layer Stock[10], Layer Estrada[20].

Any ideas for a specific plug-in or another solution?

Qgis 2.18

Answer (score 11):

You can use either the Split Vector Layer tool in the Vector drop down menu under Data Management. There is an option in the tool for selecting an attribute to split the layer by.

Alternatively there is a Split Vector Layer tool in the QGIS Geoalgorithms Toolbox. It has a similar option for splitting by an attribute field.